# IOS 8 Scan credit card name and expiration date in html form

Tags: html, ios8

How can i get Expiration date and card holder name after scanning credit card?

the attribute name="cardNumber", can helps to scan the card number.

Does is their any way to get expiration month and name fields?

Answer (score 0):

I just add autocomplete="cc-exp-year" and autocomplete="cc-exp-month"
and it works on my iPhone.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pYwbUk